# Set Up Geoserver with .sid Files

Tags: boundless-suite, image-mosaic, mrsid

I was given a folder of .sid, .sdw, and .sid.aux.xml files to use as tiles on our map. I'm pretty sure I can use ImageMosaic for this and have followed the doc at http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/image_mosaic_plugin/imagemosaic.html.
When I get to the step to add a Store and click save, I get the error "Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Argument "value" should not be null." What can I do to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: did you follow http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html#data-gdal?

Comment: Yes, but after I was done installing the native libraries, I didn't see all of the Raster Data Sources it says I should have. I don't have JP2MrSID or MrSID.

Comment: sounds like a problem installing the native libs then, what does gdalinfo --formats give you?

Comment: MrSID is in there (I can't paste the whole list in here)...

 ...
  MrSID (ro): Multi-resolution Seamless Image Database (MrSID)
  JP2MrSID (ro): MrSID JPEG2000
 ...

Comment: I have figured out the problem. I have OpenGeo Suite which I assumed set up gdal the same but it doesn't. It says I have to enable MrSID  on install. Do you know if I can change that after install? I don't want to reinstall and lose everything if I don't have to.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this? We are hoping to serve sids via Geoserver (opengeo suite) as well.

Comment: Having issues with this as well. using geoserver 2.7.2